# Deserialize XML containing an embedded xhtml element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-deserialization

I am receiving xml that contains embedded xhtml.

I would like to return the DocBody Element as a string that contains all of the xhtml, but do not know how since the xhtml is contained within the xml.  I have not seen many examples of how to do this.

I am receiving this result via an API so the XML cannot be modified.

```
<Documents xmlns="http://mycompany.com/api/v2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Document>
        <Content i:type="CreditAnalystNote">
            <DocBody>
                <xhtml>
                    <p>
                        Paragrah 1 html.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Paragrah 2 html.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Paragrah 3 html.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Paragrah 4 html.
                    </p>
                </xhtml>
            </DocBody>
        </Content>
    </Document>
</Documents>
```

The class I am using to deserialize the XML with is given as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Corporate
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Documents", Namespace = "http://cms.mycompany.com/api/v2")]
    public class RPSShareclassDocuments
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Document")]
        public List<ShareClassDocumentData> DocumentData { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ShareClassDocumentData
    {
        [XmlElement("Content")]
        public DocumentShareClassData CreditNote { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("CreditAnalystNote")]
    public class DocumentShareClassData
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string DocBody { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to deserialize the text using the following:

```
XDocument xDocResult = new XDocument();
xDocResult = ... (gets content into an XDocument)

IXmlUtils xmlUtility = new XmlUtils();
RPSShareclassDocuments document = xmlUtility.Deserialize<RPSShareclassDocuments>(xDocResult);
```

and the Deserialization method is:

```
    public T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
    {

        string szNamespace = doc.Root.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), szNamespace);
        T result;
        using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**EDIT 1**
The only way that I could figure out how to extract the XHTML from the XML was to use the following code, though this is not what I was hoping for.

```
            xDocResult = restClient.RestGET(szCurrentSecurityAPI);

        XNamespace ns = xDocResult.Root.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;
        XElement xdb = xDocResult.Root.Element(ns + "Document").Element(ns + "Content").Element(ns + "DocBody").Element(ns + "xhtml");
```

If there is a better option such as extracting the information from the XDocument directly or XSLT, I would also be interested.

Comment: Properties have to be public to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I must be missing what you mean - all the properties are public. How does that help to extract the xhtml though?